# Passing a state value in functional component in React

Tags: reactjs, promise

I am trying to use promise tracker. I used `react-promise-tracker` package.

Below the code of my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { usePromiseTracker } from "react-promise-tracker";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

const LdngIndicator = (props) => {
  const { promiseInProgress } = usePromiseTracker();
  return promiseInProgress && <Spinner />;
};

export default function LoadingIndicator() {
  return <LdngIndicator />;
}
```

parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { trackPromise } from "react-promise-tracker";
import LoadingIndicator from "./LoadingIndicator";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      randomResponse: "",
    };
  }

  apifunc = () => {
    trackPromise(
      fetch(
        "https://****.rapidapi.com/random",
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            accept: "application/json",
            "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.REACT_APP_KEY,
            "x-rapidapi-host": "host.rapidapi.com",
          },
        }
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({
            randomResponse: res,
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.error(err);
        })
    );
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.apifunc();
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <form className="jokesForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Get a new joke</label>
          <input type="submit" value="Go!"></input>
        </form>

        <main>
          {<LoadingIndicator /> ? <p>True</p> : <p>false</p>}        
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I can run this without any issues. I would like to get boolean value of the promiseInProgress in my parent component.

`promiseInProgress` changes as I make requests.

What is the best way to send this as props?

I read https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html as well as different questions on stack overflow but I was not able to find an answer to my quesiton.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: There are only 3 ways that repeated in all answers - props drilling, context API or use state management library just pick whats suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't show us your parent component though so let's assume its a functional component

//parent.jsx

```
import react, { useState } from 'react'
import Loader from 'loader.jsx'

const ParentComp = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(false)

    return <>
         <Loader setState={setState}  setState={setState} />
         <span> {`state: ${state}`} <span/>
    </>
}

export default ParentComp
```

//loader.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { usePromiseTracker } from "react-promise-tracker";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

const LdngIndicator = () => {
    const { promiseInProgress } = usePromiseTracker();

   return promiseInProgress && <Spinner />;
};

export default function LoadingIndicator({state, setState}) {
    return <>
       <button onClick={() => setState(!state)}>click</button>
       <LdngIndicator />
    </>
}
```

you get the idea? what you can easily do is to pass setState to child component and modify it from the child

Comment: I added my parent.js file. I actually use class component. Do I need to use the same type of components for both files? I remember using different types in parent and child in the past.

Comment: not necessary, I just used that for illustration

Comment: Why is there two setState props in the first line of the return in the parent.jsx? Was it meant to be just state?

Comment: I am afraid, this is not the answer to what I asked. What I am trying to get it: value of `promiseInProgress` as it changes when I make a request and pass it to the parent.js